# Rake Rails Vlad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, vlad-deployer

I'm getting an error when I run "rake vlad:setup"  The errror is  `Missing the Rails 2.1.0 gem. Please 'gem install -v=2.1.0 rails', update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.`

However Rails is installed; so it looks like something might be broken in the ways the gems are installed by RVM.  Any hints?

```
[gakins@Somnambulist gaimplan_emp]$ rails --version
Rails 2.1.0
[gakins@Somnambulist gaimplan_emp]$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (2.1.0)
[gakins@Somnambulist gaimplan_emp]$ rake vlad:setup
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails328/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails328/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["= 1.8"]
Missing the Rails 2.1.0 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.1.0 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
[gakins@Somnambulist gaimplan_emp]$
```

I am using rvm and have a gemset for this project.

Comment: Which Rails version do you use? Also Vlad is unmaintained, so be sure that you still wanna use it.

Comment: Rails 2.1.0 is what I need for this project.  I didn't realize Vlad wasn't supported.  Any other options for a deploy besides Capistrano?

Comment: It look like that there are [some small updates](https://github.com/seattlerb/vlad/commits/master) to Vlad, but it doesn't look like that it is heavily maintained. There is also [Mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/). But why not Capistrano?

Comment: Vlad looked simpler, after wrestling with Capistrano.  Capistrano looks like it had some project turmoil and I wasn't sure how supported it was/is.

Comment: There is version 3.x now, so it is still heavy maintained with big community. Give it a try once again.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz.  I think I have to use 2.x because of dependencies (older version of rails and everything else).. but it seems to be working (so goodbye Vlad).